# How to reseed an an auto increment column in a SQLite database?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sqlite, identity-column

Is it possible to reseed an auto increment column in a SQLite database, and if so, how is this done?

ie. The equivalent of `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTable', RESEED, 1)` in SQL Server.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In SQLite there is a table named SQLITE_SEQUENCE, which tracks the largest `RowId` value that a table has. You can do insert, updates and deletes on this table. For example, to mimic similar functionality as the TRUNCATE TABLE statement SQL Server you could something like:

```
DELETE FROM MyTableName;
DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = 'MyTableName';
```

In the above example all data from MyTableName is removed, and the auto increment rowid is reset by removing the value from the SQLITE_SEQUENCE table. See the documentation for [AUTOINCREMENT](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly.  Just had to add a semicolon at the end of each line.

Answer (score 6):

```
DELETE 
FROM MyTableName

select *
from SQLITE_SEQUENCE

update SQLITE_SEQUENCE 
set seq = 0
where name ='MyTableName'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could export a SQL file from the SQLite database. Then edit the generated SQL file and update the appropriate entries to the desired IDs or delete the INSERT statements. After this create a new empty database and seed it with the adjusted SQL file. The highest ID + 1 will then be the ID for a new entry...

With this way you can decide, which entries to keep and which entries should be removed as a non-destructive or even a more flexible approach.

For me it worked - clean and easy. ;)