# how to give the delected id value to new record in sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, identity

```
CREATE TABLE "Customer" (
  "Id" integer primary key autoincrement not null,
  "Name" varchar,
  "Mid" varchar,
  "Year" integer,
  "Semester" integer 
)

+----+---------+-----+------+----------+    
| Id | Name    | Mid | Year | Semester |
+----+---------+-----+------+----------+
| 13 | sampath | 44  | 4    | 1        |
| 14 | vijay   | 12  | 4    | 2        |
| 15 | john    | 13  | 4    | 2        |
| 16 | mary    | 14  | 4    | 2        |
+----+---------+-----+------+----------+
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I use the previously deleted id value to new record. In
   sqlite we don't have identity column so I used the autoincrement
   keyword. Can I use set identity_insert here?
2. Is there any possibility of using **DBCC** to reset id values?

Comment: "How can I use the previously deleted id value to new record."  What are you asking?  Are you saying you deleted a record but don't remember the id that you used when deleting it? SQLite has a last insert rowid. http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html

Comment: i have deleted a record with id =5 for example and when i inserted a new record then i get id=10 now how to replace the gap for id =5 @RobertDupuy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122865/how-to-reseed-an-an-auto-increment-column-in-a-sqlite-database